# Parsing HTML data in SQL Server 2016 for large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to parse the HTML data which exists in one of my table but issue is the table size is huge and I can't use the function provided here. I was just wondering if there is any efficient way to parse the data from a huge table.

I tried the solution here and it works great but can't use for huge table.
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/

Sample code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27baba/1

Data looks like this:

```
ID  Valuen
  1 <t><some>this is the value</t></some>another value . <none> 3rd value </none>
  2 <t><bold>Correct value </t></bold>new value . <color> salary </color>
```

Sample Output:

```
 ID     Valuen
   1     this is the value another value 3rd value
   2     Correct value  new value . salary
```

Please note that I tried using XML parsing as well but it does not work as its unable to convert all the data to XML.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do that in SQL? It's the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Yeah agreed but the data already exists in table and now we want to use the existing data ...ideally should have been parsed from the application side

Comment: What is the issue with the code in the linked article? Is it just down to performance? Whilst you can do string processing in T-Sql, working at scale is not one of its strengths.

Comment: yes performance is big issue in that article ..works for small data only but not for large tables

Comment: The question is not really parse, but rather strip?

Comment: Why not try to gather unique "tags" and just replace them with empty space?

Comment: Try and convert all tags to self closing ones: `select ID, /*trim(*/try_cast(replace(replace(valuen, '>', '/> '), '</', '<') as xml).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
from test`

Comment: @lptr thank you for your help but for some reason its not able to convert all the rows for some reason ..it works for these 2 samples but not when I apply across whole table

Answer (score 3):

If open to a helper function

**Normalized Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pWvcvFaw)**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  test A
 Cross Apply   [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](ValueN,'>','<') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       this is the value
1   2       another value .
1   3       3rd value
2   1       Correct value
2   2       new value .
2   3       salary
```

**Same as Above, Just Added a `string_agg()`**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  test A
 Cross Apply  ( Select NewVal = string_agg(RetVal,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RetSeq) 
                  From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](ValueN,'>','<')  
              )B
```

**Results**

```
ID  NewVal
1   this is the value another value .   3rd value
2   Correct value  new value .   salary
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON] (@String nvarchar(max),@Delim1 nvarchar(100),@Delim2 nvarchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = trim(Value)
             From  OpenJSON( N'["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delim1,'","')+N'"]' )

          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

Comment: thank you I can try this and see how it impacts the performance

Comment: @Avi Let me know how they compare.  I would be very interested in the REAL WORL results.

Comment: Thank you @John for providing different way of handling this but this also seems to have performance issue ..I have to see if they can fix the table itself rather than converting the data

Comment: @Avi Fair enough.  Just curious...  do you have many rows or LARGE html files?

Comment: Around 10 M rows with nvarchar (Max) as data type

Comment: @Avi Yup.  That will cost ya  :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution on your data set.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID int, tokens VARCHAR (500)); 
INSERT INTO @tbl(id, tokens) VALUES 
(1, '<t><some>this is the value</t></some>another value .  <none> 3rd value </none>'),
(2, '<t><bold>Correct value </t></bold>new value .  <color> salary </color>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.ID
    , Result = STRING_AGG(LEFT(token, CHARINDEX('<', token + '<') - 1), SPACE(1))
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, '>', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(x)
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/r[text()][not(substring(text()[1],1,1)="<")]/text()') AS t2(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('.','VARCHAR(500)')) AS t3(token)
GROUP BY ID;
```

**Output**

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | this is the value another value . 3rd value |
| 2 | Correct value new value . salary |